# jquery slider - animating timeline

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery slider function for a timeline

```
$("#content-slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 300,
    step: 1,
    change: handleSliderChange,
    //start:    getImageWidth,
    slide: handleSliderSlide
  });

  function handleSliderSlide(event, ui) {

  $("#content-scroll").prop({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 300) });

 if (ui.value >= 7 && ui.value <= 13) {
  $('#marker_10').animate({opacity: 'hide'}, 100, function () { $(this).parent('div').animate({marginTop: '100px'}, {duration:1000, queue:false }).addClass('up').find('p').animate({opacity: 'show'} ) }) 
  }

if (ui.value > 13 || ui.value < 7 && ($('div#container_10').hasClass('up'))) {
   $('div.up').stop(true)
   $('#container_10').removeClass('up').find('p').fadeOut('fast').end().animate({marginTop:'165px'}, {duration:500, complete:function() {$(this).find('img.marker').fadeIn() }, queue:false})
  }
}
```

http://asla.dev.1over0.com/html/slider/bacardi_last.html

It animates ok when I scroll left to right but when I scroll right to left then I get some issues where elements are fading out and displaying correctly 
any information would be appreciated; this is all done on the front end currently
Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of a specific right to left issue? I've been scrolling back and forth and I'm not sure what I'm looking for. Also, do I get some free booze if I solve your problem? :P

Comment: thanks for the feedback the animation is more 'jumpy' that way and the timeline marker or text doesn't always fade out or fade in correctly based on the value - the animation is almost to be wave like; the animation of up and down works properly if I had all the paragraphs permanently http://asla.dev.1over0.com/html/slider/bacardi_five.html the animation is supposed to be wave like.  If I worked for Bacardi I would give you all the free booze for helping me with this; but i got this project through a developer who works with an ad agency but couldn't do it so passed it along to my small group

Comment: i meant 'hide' not had all paragraph elements

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution directly, but some notes that may help.

- The down animation isn't triggered until the slider is past the left edge of the active content. To the right, it's triggered immediately after the slider moves off of the vertical line.
- Several of the sections have content cut off the bottom - seems like a simple height issue?
- When sliding right to left, the vertical line doesn't disappear.
- You may want to add a "title" to "#content-slider a" as new users may not be sure what it does at first. A simple "Slide Me" would suffice :)
- One additional note, when the browser window is small (around 800px or so, didn't check exactly), the content jumps below the slider bar.

Just thinking about how I'd approach this task; I'd setup animations in a function for animating up, then one for down. After I can verify they work on button press (or some non-slider trigger) I'd work on ensuring the "active" areas are setup correct on the time line (either the vertical line or the whole "active" content box, personally I'd do something in the middle). After those pieces are setup, should be an easy task to trigger the up movement function when the slider is in the "active" area and down when it leaves, making sure they don't run at the same time.

Hope it helps!